# SnapSVG: Remove mask from an element (unmask)

Tags: mask, snap.svg

I have my JS code in which I use Snap SVG. At some point I use

```
element.attr({mask:maskelement});
```

In that snippet, `element` and `maskelement` are two elements inside my svg.

Now I want to remove the mask. What would be the correct code that achieves this?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/snapsvg/Fi0z82RqiDI), although I feel it's not the best answer.

Basically, you set the mask's display property to none with the following code

`maskelement.attr("display", "none");`

Although the SVG *looks* like there's no more mask, it doesn't truly remove the mask. I think there's a better answer available.

Comment: Still I thank you for that answer, though I will leave this question unanswered if that is alright with you. Maybe someone will have "the way-to-go". =)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. For some reason,

```
element.attr('mask', null');
```

does not work, so to make it work, I had to do:

```
element.node.removeAttribute('mask');
```